# How do I recover the Facebook account password?

Tags: facebook, account-management, account-recovery, facebook-account

I have forgotten my Facebook account password and also I have no access to the number which I use to log-in to Facebook account.

On this page (see the image below) they are asking for a government photo-ID to verify my account. The problem is that I don't have a driving license, voter ID card, passport etc. All I have is a school ID card but that hasn't worked for me. Is there any other way to recover my password?

[image: screen shot of account recovery form]

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to recover an account without a government issued ID. You can recover your account using your email account. If you don't have access to your email and phone number you need to provide a government issued ID at any cost to verify that it belongs to you legally. From my personal experience, I provided government issued ID but I was not able to recover my account after that.

Answer (score 0):

Normally one would have access to the email account from setting up the account in the first place... barring that, if you do not currently have a photo ID, it should not be impossible for you to get one. They do not indicate that it must be an ID that you had prior to account creation ;).