# How To Recover Facebook Password?

Tags: facebook, account-recovery

I have lost my Facebook password but I want to recover my Facebook password back. So please if anyone know how to recover Facebook password then reply me.

Comment: Also: [How do I recover the Facebook account password?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74246/354)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't recover a Facebook password. You need to reset it to a completely different password. You can reset your password using this link: https://www.facebook.com/login/identify