# Locked out of Facebook

Tags: facebook, account-recovery

I no longer have access to the phone number not email address that I used to create my account and I have sent a copy of my ID to Facebook several times and still didn't get a response. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover the Facebook account password?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/74246/how-do-i-recover-the-facebook-account-password)

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to reset your Facebook password because you can't access associated email address or mobile phone number.
Here are some things you can try to get back into your account so you can reset your password.

**Try logging in with an alternate email or phone number**
You may be able to get back into your Facebook account by using an alternate email or mobile phone number listed on your account.

If you don't know what alternate information you have:

1. Go to https://www.facebook.com/login/identify and follow the instructions.
2. Make sure to use a computer or mobile phone that you have previously used to log into your Facebook account.
3. Learn how to [reset your password](https://www.facebook.com/help/213395615347144?helpref=faq_content) once you get back into your account.

**Try to recover your email account**

- If you signed up for Facebook with your email, contact your email service provider to regain access to the email on your Facebook account. For example, many email service providers have a **Trouble signing in?** option on their sign in screen.
- If you regain access to your email, you can finish the steps to [reset your password](https://www.facebook.com/help/213395615347144?helpref=faq_content).

For more details see [I can't log in to Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/105487009541643?helpref=faq_content) page.